# Creating automatic pull request via a Github app

Tags: github, octokit

I am very new to the Github app concept. I already created a Github app and installed it in one of my repository. By using octokit library and installation token of the Github app I can create an issue on the repository. However, I can create a pull request via this Github app's installation access token. Github app only can create issues or just subscribe the events. Do you have any idea how can achieve it.

```
# github app
@client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => "installation access token")

response = @client.create_pull_request(repo, base_branch, "test_branch", pr_title, pr_body)
```

Getting this response:

`403 - Resource not accessible by integration // See: https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request (Octokit::Forbidden)`

I created a Github app and tried to create automatic pull requests without using a Github user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a access token to make a PR.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).